# GET and POST with node boostrap 4 form and python 3 flask

Tags: python, node.js, flask, npm, bootstrap-4

I have a form in an html file like so, and I need to pass this over to a python file, which will do a bunch of stuff and return the output back to the html page. The confusing thing is I use `npm start` for starting up the website and would usually use some other flask server for doing flask stuff. How would I make this work? Do I even need a flask server?

The returned data from python should either go back to the same HTML element or to another element.

HTML:

```
<form action="path/my_script.py" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="python_input">python input or link</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="python_input" aria-describedby="pythonHelp" placeholder="Enter python_input required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!
            </div>
                 <small id="pythonHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Pick your diamond from James Allen's
                       <a href="https://www.example.com/">website</a> and copy paste the info or URL here</small>
     </div>
</form>
```

Python 3:

````
import json
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/myForm.html', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def regression():
    python_input= request.form['python_input']
    #do more stuff here
    return 'you posted the '+str(python_input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=12345, debug=True)```
````